Stuck on task on decimal notation of a number
In the decimal representation of an irreducible fraction $\frac{m}{n}$, each digit after the decimal point (except for the first one) is less than the sum of its two neighboring digits by the same number $k$. Prove that the denominator $n \leq 819$.
My thoughts on this problem:
Consider $\left\{ \frac{m}{n} \right\} = 0.a_1 a_2 \ldots a_i a_1 a_2 \ldots a_i \ldots = \frac{(a_1 a_2 \ldots a_i)}{(10^p - 1)}$. I noticed that 819 is a divisor of $10^6 - 1$. But that's all I've done with this problem, and I don't know what to do next.
Upd:
$a3 = a2 + k - a1, 
a4 = a3 + k - a2 = (a2 + k - a1) + k - a2 = 2k - a1, 
a5 = a4 + k - a3 = (2k - a1) + k - (a2 + k - a1) = 2k - a2, 
a6 = a5 + k - a4 = (2k - a2) + k - (2k - a1) = a1 - a2 + k, 
a7 = a6 + k - a5 = a1$
So, the period is maximum 6.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

I suggest:  work this for particular $k$.  Look for structure in those arguments.  For that matter, just try to write down examples of rational numbers that pass your test.

@lulu, that was first that i tried in this task and it gave me nothing

How many of these numbers have you been able to write down?  Please edit your post to list them, or at least some of them.

@lulu, i have some updates:
$ a3 = a2 + k - a1
a4 = a3 + k - a2 = (a2 + k - a1) + k - a2 = 2k - a1
a5 = a4 + k - a3 = (2k - a1) + k - (a2 + k - a1) = 2k - a2
a6 = a5 + k - a4 = (2k - a2) + k - (2k - a1) = a1 - a2 + k
a7 = a6 + k - a5 = a1 $
So, the period is maximum 6.

Good!  I suggest editing your post to include that, it's obviously very relevant to this problem.  Note too that what you have written shows that the decimal is uniquely determined by the triple $(a_1,a_2, k)$ so it's easy to see that there are only finitely many possibilities for it.  Thus, you could simply check them all.  Of course, you can probably save yourself a lot of work there.

Also worth noting:  what you wrote proves that the condition implies rationality...there was no need to assume that at the start.

@lulu but this is math task and i guess that to check all cases won't be the correct solution:(

As a suggestion to speed the exhaustive search:  Adding a fixed constant to each entry in the decimal preserves the property (though of course it might change good digits into values over $9$).    Thus you can assume that $a_1=1$ (up to possibly adding a multiple of $\frac 19$).

Exhaustion is a perfectly valid technique though I agree you want to cut the search down to something more reasonable.  As it stands the number of triple could be as high as $10\times 10\times 20$ (or something like that), though of course most of those don't give valid decimals.  My immediately prior comment suggests a way to vastly reduce the space.

I suggest:  try to write down specific examples.  They exist!  But it's not so easy to find them.  That ought to mean that the true search space is extremely small.

@lulu, i solved! i will write the solution later, but the main idea that a1a2a3a4a5a6= 10^6*a1 + ... + a6 and then remeber that a6 = a1 - a2 + k and etcetra. So if substitute all available data, numerator and denominator will be reduced by 1221 and the denominator will just remain 819.

Excellent.  Good work.  When you have your complete solution, I suggest posting it below.  That way, users here can check your work and the site can close the question.

Is this from some math contest? It feels like it might. If so, you should give the source. Just so that we know it isn't an on-going question. Anyway, it looks like you have figured out how to write all the decimals in terms of the first two (as well as the parameter $k$). My upvote for that! If you don't see a way forward, it's time to start testing what kind of numbers you get. Do keep in mind the range of the digits $a_i$.

@JyrkiLahtonen, posted the solution, the problem is not from the ongoing math contest,  a problem from the math club where I study.

Consider the fractional part of the number $\frac{m}{n}$.
Let our number be of the form $0.a_1 a_2 \ldots a_i a_1 a_2 \ldots a_i \ldots $
$a_3 = a_2 + k - a_1,$
$
a_4 = a_3 + k - a_2 = (a_2 + k - a_1) + k - a_2 = 2k - a_1,
$
$a_5 = a_4 + k - a_3 = (2k - a_1) + k - (a_2 + k - a_1) = 2k - a_2,$
$a_6 = a_5 + k - a_4 = (2k - a_2) + k - (2k - a_1) = a_1 - a_2 + k,$
$a_7 = a_6 + k - a_5 = a_1.$
Thus, the maximum period of the fraction is 6, and any period is determined by the triplet of numbers $(a_1, a_2, k)$
The fractional part can be expressed as:
$\{ \frac{m}{n} \} = 0.a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 a_5 a_6 a_1 \ldots = \frac{a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 a_5 a_6}{10^6 - 1} = \frac{10^6 a_1 + \ldots + a_6}{999999}$
$= \frac{98901 a_1 + 10989 a_2 + 1221 k}{999999} = \frac{81 a_1 + 9 a_2 + k}{819}.$
Thus, the maximum value of $n$ is $819$

@JyrkiLahtonen why? so i have shown that our numbers equals something divided by 819, isn't that what I had to prove in the problem

@JyrkiLahtonen ah, i understood, so i need now to check all cases where the period is 3, 4 and 5?(

Oops! Sorry, for some reason I was thinking that the task was to find the largest possible denominator.

@JyrkiLahtonen fixed, but i guess this solution doesn't work when for example period = 5

Your argument shows that $6$ is always a period. The smallest period could be a factor of $6$, but you don't need to worry about them. My (now deleted) comment was based on a misread.

this is good (+1).   If you wanted to prove that the maximum is realized (though this was not asked) you could cite an example, e.g.  $(a_1, a_2, k)=(1,1,4)=.\overline {114774}=\frac {94}{819}$.
